# Selenium JS - touch event to swipe element

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, electron

I have a component in HTML that listens to touch events touchstart, touchend, etc.
A functionality is implemented for "swipe left" which removes the element from the DOM.
I need to implement an automatic test function via Selenium-Webdriver and JS which performs the touch logic, so the expected result removing the element.
I checked everything and in ChatGPT but couldn't find any solution for this.

I really appriciate the help :)

My attempts:

**first attempt:**

```
    await driver.actions()
      .move({ origin: element })
      .press()
      .move({ x: endX, y: endY })
      .release()
      .perform();
```

didnt work!

**second attempt:**

```
await driver.executeScript(
      `
      var element = arguments[0];
      var startX = element.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.pageXOffset;
      var startY = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
      var endX = startX - 100;  // Adjust the value as per your needs

      var swipeEvent = new MouseEvent('touchstart', {
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          view: window,
          clientX: startX,
          clientY: startY
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(swipeEvent);

      /* also added here touchmove and touchend */
      `,
      element
    );
```

didnt work!

**third + fourth attempts:**

tried to use the libraries TouchActions and TouchSequence, but after some research, i relized that they are deprecated.

I wanted to try maybe inserting chromeOptions to swap my mouse to have touch abillities, but I looked as much as trying to add flags, which didn't really do the job (i didn't dug into it that much).

**update:**

I tried adding options to the driver, that set mobile emulation, as shown below:

```
const options = new Options().setMobileEmulation({mobileName: 'Nexus 5'})
```

so that maybe it will have touch capabilities, but, relized that i can't, since my system is running on electron, and the options are imported only by the following browsers: ie, chrome, safari, edge, firefox.

than, i asked GPT for alternatives to simulate touch events, he gave me a few libraries that emulate touch events, such as: hammerJS, interactJS, and some more.

thats what i wrote for the hammerJS library:

```
const htmlElement = document.getElementById('element1');
const mc = new Hammer(htmlElement);
mc.add(new Hammer.Swipe({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT }));

mc.on('swipeleft', () => {
  // Handle the swipe left gesture
});

const swipeLeft = async (element) => {
  await driver.executeScript(`
    const target = arguments[0];
    const mc = new Hammer(target);

    const swipeEvent = new Hammer.Swipe();
    swipeEvent.direction = Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT;

    const eventData = {
      type: 'swipe',
      direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT
    };

    mc.emit(swipeEvent, eventData);
  `, element);
};

const element = await driver.findElement(By.id('element1'));
await swipeLeft(element);
```

but got an error of: "window is not defined"

which happends because this libraries are used within a browser environment, where the window object is part of the global scope.

however, in certain environments or test automation frameworks, the global scope may be different, leading to this error.

it also happend with the interactJS, only with the document is not defined instead of window.

the code for interactJS:

```
const htmlElement = document.getElementById('element1');

interact(htmlElement)
  .draggable({
    modifiers: [
      interact.modifiers.restrictRect({
        restriction: 'parent',
        endOnly: true
      })
    ],
    listeners: {
      move(event) {
        const { dx, dy } = event;
        htmlElement.style.transform = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`;
      }
    }
  });
  
  
const swipeLeft = async (element) => {
  await driver.executeScript(`
    const target = arguments[0];

    interact(target)
      .gesturable({
        onmove: (event) => {
          const { dx, dy } = event;
          target.style.transform = 'translate(' + dx + 'px, ' + dy + 'px)';
        },
        onend: () => {
          target.style.transform = 'translate(0, 0)';
        }
      })
      .fire({
        type: 'gesturemove',
        deltaX: -100,
        deltaY: 0
      })
      .fire({ type: 'gestureend' });
  `, element);
};

const element = await driver.findElement(By.id('element1'));
await swipeLeft(element);
```